# Printing multiple java JComponents in high quality

Tags: java, jcomponent

Has anyone ever tried to print more than one "text" components in a single printjob?

The components I need to print with the print method I am calling are these:

```
jEditorPane1.print();  
jTable1.print();
```

The above methods print in good quality BUT they come out as 2 different print jobs. Is there a way so as to come out as a single print job?

Comment: You can first paint both onto an image, and then print that image.

Comment: in this case won't the quality of the print become low?

Comment: I'll admit I'm not familiar with the printing API nor its provided functionality, but I feel like I've before seen a similar question here which received an answer similar to that.  Why would the quality of the print be low though?